# Parse a line of user input word by word in C++

Tags: c++, stl

So I'm trying to parse an unknown amount of strings from user input in C++ and want to store them in a vector.

I have no idea what to do.

So so say the user enters this:
Money Linux fire Computers

I want to be able to take each word and store it into a vector. I originally had something that looked like this, but it failed horribly:

```
while(in!="")
{
    cin>>in;
    input.push_back(in);
}
```

Any pointers to where I should start?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890164/how-can-i-split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-into-an-array

Comment: This is called [string tokenizing (or splitting in some frameworks)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c).

Comment: "in" is a string variable.  It failed because it would not exit out of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Never use input operations outside a conditional check. The canonical way to write your code is:

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
for (std::string word; std::cin >> word; ) { result.push_back(word); }
```

(In C++11, you can say `result.emplace_back(std::move(word));` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

```
string in;
while (cin >> in) {
    input.push_back(in);
}
```

The `>>` operator on a stream returns the stream. A std::istream is converted into a boolean by checking whether it is in a good state. If it reaches the end of the input, the expression will be `false` on the next read.

When the extraction fails, a blank string is not written to the `in` argument, which is why your loop was not working.

Comment: Having the EOF bit set doesn't make your stream evaluate to `false`. It's the *fail bit* that does this.

Comment: That makes more sense. The EOF bit is set after the last successful read, and then the next read causes the void* operator to return NULL. Thanks for the correction.